# Visibility in mountains and hills

Tags: hiking, mountains

Is the visibility better to west than east? I was on one mountain in the west and could not see the one far in the east, not even close. The guy who was in one mountain the east, said he saw the mountain in the west. The distance is about 60 miles, 100 km.

So it came to debate if visibility is generally better to the west than east,...?

Comment: Highly location, time, weather dependent. Likely unanswerable in any meaningful way.

Comment: Was one of you looking into the sun?

Comment: Do both of you have the same level of eyesight? Or does one use thick glasses?

Comment: I have good eyesight and binoculars did not help. Towards south, where the sun was the visibility was worse. But south has higher temperatures and the air can hold more moisture.I wasn't looking in the sun.  East - west axis I don't know. It seemed that there was better visibility towars west in midday.

Comment: One of the worst things a questioner can do is hold the original text a sacred and then drip feed the info via the comments.

Comment: @MartinF, I've never heard this critique stated so eloquently!

Comment: @MichaelHall - Feel free to use it (but credit his eloquentness martin f)

Comment: If @MartinF and MichaelHall don' have anything meaningful to say related to question then don't. The question was about visibility.

Comment: @AlexJ. Yes, and someone asked you for more details. You chose to provide them in the comments instead of trying to clarify the question. (It's normally a problem only with newbies.) If you're willing to improve the Q, i'd be willing to upvote it, and argue that it is not "opinion-based".

Comment: I just downvoted for not taking the hint to improve your question as Martin suggested.  Because that's the purpose of comments, to clarify and improve the question...  Some simply choose to provide their meaningful feedback via subtle, possibly humorous, and sometimes mildly sarcastic hints instead of stating the obvious "*I suggest you add this information to the question so we can delete this comment string.*"  That said, if you add the new information to the question I will quite happily delete my comments and remove my downvote.  That's how this site works...

Comment: P.S.  The question shouldn't have been closed for being opinion based.  The current answer is factual and correct.

Answer (score 5):

There is no visible or measurable variation in visibility that is based on whether you are looking west or east.

There will be innumerable reasons why at a particular time on a particular day one person may have had better visibility than someone else, but that would be a long list of conditions including position of the sun, location, time, weather, local conditions, eye health of individuals, and so on.